# Re-MQL4 code limiting number of open symbols

Tags: mql4

Thanks Daniel for your response, the code is in `start(){...}` as below.

I am a bit confused why it is not working.

Hope the details I have provided are enough :

```
int SYMBOL_NUMBER_LIMIT = 3;

int start()
{
    string COUNTED_SYMBOLS[]; ArrayResize( COUNTED_SYMBOLS, SYMBOL_NUMBER_LIMIT, 0 );

    for (  int s = 0; s <  SYMBOL_NUMBER_LIMIT; s++ ) COUNTED_SYMBOLS[s] = "";

    int  SYMBOLS_IN_TRADE_SO_FAR = 0;
    bool NEW_TRADE_PERMISSION    = True;
    int  ALL_POSITIONS           = OrdersTotal(); // PositionsTotal();

    if (  ALL_POSITIONS >  0 )
    {     
          for (  int index = 0; index <  ALL_POSITIONS; index++ )
          {
                 string THIS_SYMBOL = OrderSymbol(); // PositionGetSymbol( index );
                 bool   Symbol_already_counted = False;

                 for (  int i = 0; i < SYMBOL_NUMBER_LIMIT; i++ )
                 {
                        if (  COUNTED_SYMBOLS[i] == THIS_SYMBOL )
                        {
                              Symbol_already_counted = True;
                              break;
                        }

                        if (  Symbol_already_counted ) continue;
                        else
                        {     
                              SYMBOLS_IN_TRADE_SO_FAR++;
                           // if (  SYMBOLS_IN_TRADE_SO_FAR >= SYMBOL_NUMBER_LIMIT )
                              if (  SYMBOLS_IN_TRADE_SO_FAR == SYMBOL_NUMBER_LIMIT )
                              {     
                                    NEW_TRADE_PERMISSION = False;
                                    break;
                              }
                              for (  int j = 0; j <  SYMBOL_NUMBER_LIMIT; j++ )
                                     if (  COUNTED_SYMBOLS[j] == "" )
                                     {
                                           COUNTED_SYMBOLS[j] = THIS_SYMBOL;
                                           break;
                                     }
                        }
                 }
          }
    }
```

Comment: and what is the reason of calling this all block in `start()` function? Your ea should work in start() function and sometimes, when necessary, go to another function, let us calling it bool IsNewTradeAllowed() that returns your variable NEW_TRADE_PERMISSION, and  your ea makes a decision based on the result of this function

Comment: Please Dan, How do I go about what you have suggested. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
input int SYMBOL_NUMBER_LIMIT;
int start(){
    // some logic
    int direction; string symbol;//these parameters to initialize to send a new trade
    // some function to get a new direction and symbol
    if(direction!=0 && symbol!=NULL){
       bool allowSendNewTrade=isNewTradeAllowed(symbol);
       if(allowSendNewTrade)OrderSend(symbol,lot,direction>0?OP_BUY:OP_SELL,0,0,0);
    }

    return(0);
}
bool isNewTradeAllowed(string symbolInQuestion){
   string symbols[];
   int SYMBOLS_IN_TRADE_SO_FAR=0;
   ArrayResize(symbols,OrdersTotal());
   for(int i=OrdersTotal()-1;i>=0;i--){
      if(!OrderSelect(i,SELECT_BY_POS))continue;
      string currentSymbol=OrderSymbol();
      boolean symbolAlreadyInList=false;
      for(int j=SYMBOLS_IN_TRADE_SO_FAR-1;j>=0;j--){
         if(symbols[j]==currentSymbol){
            symbolAlreadyInList=true;
            break;
         }
      }
      if(!symbolAlreadyInList)
         symbols[SYMBOLS_IN_TRADE_SO_FAR++]=currentSymbol;
   }
   if(SYMBOLS_IN_TRADE_SO_FAR>SYMBOL_NUMBER_LIMIT)
      return false;
   if(SYMBOLS_IN_TRADE_SO_FAR==SYMBOL_NUMBER_LIMIT){
      for(int j=SYMBOLS_IN_TRADE_SO_FAR-1;j>=0;j--){
         if(symbols[SYMBOLS_IN_TRADE_SO_FAR]==symbolInQuestion)
            return true;
      }
      return false;
   }
   return true; //SYMBOLS_IN_TRADE_SO_FAR<SYMBOL_NUMBER_LIMIT
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code was missing the  **`{...}`**-code-block syntax closing-bracket.

```
int SYMBOL_NUMBER_LIMIT = 3;

int start()
{
    string COUNTED_SYMBOLS[]; ArrayResize( COUNTED_SYMBOLS, SYMBOL_NUMBER_LIMIT, 0 );

    for (  int s = 0; s <  SYMBOL_NUMBER_LIMIT; s++ ) COUNTED_SYMBOLS[s] = "";

    int  SYMBOLS_IN_TRADE_SO_FAR = 0;
    bool NEW_TRADE_PERMISSION    = True;
    int  ALL_POSITIONS           = OrdersTotal(); // PositionsTotal();

    if (  ALL_POSITIONS >  0 )
    {     
          for (  int index = 0; index <  ALL_POSITIONS; index++ )
          {
                 string THIS_SYMBOL = OrderSymbol(); // PositionGetSymbol( index );
                 bool   Symbol_already_counted = False;

                 for (  int i = 0; i < SYMBOL_NUMBER_LIMIT; i++ )
                 {
                        if (  COUNTED_SYMBOLS[i] == THIS_SYMBOL )
                        {
                              Symbol_already_counted = True;
                              break;
                        }

                        if (  Symbol_already_counted ) continue;
                        else
                        {     
                              SYMBOLS_IN_TRADE_SO_FAR++;
                           // if (  SYMBOLS_IN_TRADE_SO_FAR >= SYMBOL_NUMBER_LIMIT )
                              if (  SYMBOLS_IN_TRADE_SO_FAR == SYMBOL_NUMBER_LIMIT )
                              {     
                                    NEW_TRADE_PERMISSION = False;
                                    break;
                              }
                              for (  int j = 0; j <  SYMBOL_NUMBER_LIMIT; j++ )
                                     if (  COUNTED_SYMBOLS[j] == "" )
                                     {
                                           COUNTED_SYMBOLS[j] = THIS_SYMBOL;
                                           break;
                                     }
                        }
                 }
          }
    }
} // <-------------------------------------THIS ONE WAS MISSING, COMPILER WAS NOT HAPPY
```

Comment: It compiles well but the problem is that it doesn't work the way I want. It opens more than 3 symbols

Comment: Great to hear that, Sir. If you now object that the behaviour of the code is not the one you would like to have, the code has to be changed. **This is exactly how computers** ( nothing but large, yet Finite State, Automata that obey every your instruction ) **work.** Re-formulate your computing strategy algorithm and make the code meet it. That simple.